# In Meteor, is Meteor.wrapAsync blocking other calls?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor

In Meteor JS code, I am using HTTP.get method to call server inside a method. I must return result to client, so I am wrapping this function with 
`Meteor.wrapAsync` to get a Synchronous function.

```
var httpSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.get, this);
var result = httpSync(myUrl);
```

My question is - Will `Meteor.wrapAsync(AsyncFunction)` block other requests? Will it affect parallel execution of multiple requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't block the entire server. Meteor uses the [fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers) package to provide "synchronous looking" functions which don't block the entire server.

However, it will block other methods from the same user. If you want other methods from that user to run simultaneously, call `this.unblock()` inside the method:

> On the server, methods from a given client run one at a time. The N+1th invocation from a client won't start until the Nth invocation returns. However, you can change this by calling `this.unblock`. This will allow the N+1th invocation to start running in a new fiber.

By the way, you don't need to `Meteor.wrapAsync` `HTTP.get`, since it can already be used synchronously. `wrapAsync` is intended to be used with external libraries that are not designed for Meteor.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the additional tip of this.unblock().